# How can the voltage of the original battery differ so much from the voltage of the original adapter?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charging, adapter, laptop

It's about Xiaomi Mi Notebook Pro 15.6" 2019 JYU4148CN.

The original battery has a voltage of 7.6V and a current of 7.9Ah, the total Capacity is 60,040 mWh.
[image]

The original adapter has a voltage of 20V and a current of 3.25Ah, the final Capacity is 65,000 mWh
[image]

It turns out that the adapter voltage is almost 3 times higher than the battery voltage, isn't that bad for the laptop? I read that the voltage should not differ by more than 1-1.5 volts.

Comment: Welcome! _”The original adapter has a voltage of 20V and a current of 3.25Ah”_ No it does not. One more of the same, _“current of 7.9Ah”_ Please check again. Also, please read up on both these Wikipedia articles and think about how they are different: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_(physics)

Comment: That's actually a USB power supply in your picture. It powers the laptop, which can use some of that power to run a charge. USB itself doesn't charge anything.

Answer (score 1):

The adapter is not a charger, it is just a power supply for a charger.

The charger circuitry for the battery is located somewhere on laptop motherboard, between the power supply and battery.

Same thing with mobile phones etc.